# providing a designated initializer for a custom NSView in Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa, nsview

I have a custom NSView Class that looks like:

```
class MyClass: NSView
{
    var myClassVar: NSColor
}
```

Naturally, Xcode is complaining that my class has no initializers, so I need to override the designated initializer so I can initialize myClassVar.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this;

```
       class MyClass: NSView
        {
            var myClassVar: NSColor! // the optional mark ! to be noticed.

            override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
                super.init(frame:frameRect);
            }

            required init(coder: NSCoder) {
                 super.init(coder: coder)
            }

            //or customized constructor/ init
            init(frame frameRect: NSRect, otherInfo:Int) {
                super.init(frame:frameRect);
                // other code
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you give your color a default value, the initializers from NSView should still work.

Here are several ways to do this:

```
var myClassVar: NSColor?
var myClassVar: NSColor! // make sure to set this before you actually access it
var myClassVar: NSColor = NSColor.clearColor()
```

The second example (implicitly unwrapped optional) is what Apple does with IBOutlets. Otherwise you would need to have an initializer that sets each of your variables to a non-null value in your init methods.

For more information about this, see [Swift Initialization and the Pain of Optionals](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/11/20/swift-initialisation.html), which discusses these solutions:

- Instantiating it before the call to super.init.
- Optional variable (`NSColor?`), instantiating it after super.init
- Implicitly unwrapped optional variable (`NSColor!`)
- Using a lazy property
- Using a lazy property with a closure